# Why must the image of the identity of nonzero ring $A$ must be a zero divisor of the codomain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Lets say I have a ring homomorphism $f$ which maps from the nonzero rings $A$ to $B$, both of which have identities, but it maps the identity of $A$ to something other than the identity of $B$.
Why is it that the image of the identity of $A$ must be a zero divisor of $B$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $1-f(1)$.  We have $f(1)(1-f(1))=f(1)-f(1)^2=f(1-1^2)=0$.  So either $f(1)$ is a zero divisor or $1-f(1)=0$, i.e. $f(1)=1$.

(In fact, you don't even need to assume $B$ has an identity.  If $f(1)$ is not an identity for $B$, then there is some $x\in B$ such that either $f(1)x\neq x$ or $xf(1)\neq x$.  In the first case, we get that $f(1)(f(1)x-x)=0$, and in the second case we get that $(xf(1)-x)f(1)=0$.)